# how can i detect which buttoncolumn user clicked when both button are commandname="Select" from code behind?

Tags: asp.net

i have 2 select `Button` controls in a `GridView` like this

```
<asp:datagrid style="Z-INDEX: 0" id="DataGrid1" runat="server" Width="936px"      
HorizontalAlign="Justify" CellPadding="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
AllowCustomPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">

<asp:ButtonColumn Text="Button 1" CommandName="Select">
<HeaderStyle Width="5%"></HeaderStyle>
</asp:ButtonColumn>

<asp:ButtonColumn Text="Button 2" CommandName="Select">
<HeaderStyle Width="5%"></HeaderStyle>
</asp:ButtonColumn>

</asp:datagrid>
```

In code behind in `DataGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged` how can i detect which button user has clicked

```
private void DataGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(//user click button 1) {}
    else // user clicked button 2 {}
}
```

thank for your answer

Comment: Why do you need to specify the same CommandName value to the two buttons ?

Comment: because they are nearly same function button 1 clicks to view selected row, button 2 to selects row to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To response to row commands as in your case, you need to handle `GridView` [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event.

The `GridView` [SeletedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event is using to capture selection changing only. That means, if you pressed a command row on an already selected row, the `SelectedIndexChanged` is not going to fired.